# Memory management in operating systems

Tags: operating-system

Is there any difference between memory management techniques and memory management schemes? If yes, please explain. I know memory management schemes are paging and segmentation but what are the techniques for memory management, if there is a difference between the two?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about the difference between the words "schemes" and "techniques", but those aren't technical terms with precise meanings.  Most people would regard these two phrases as different ways of saying the same thing.

Comment: Hey I was reading in a study material and they have asked the same question, but I was wondering just the same as you have said..

Comment: @HiteshSikka which study material?

Comment: @Sedat: It was asked in a ppt that I received from slide share on operating system